# How to change Outlooks CTRl+Backspace behavior?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

Every single application I know of, deletes the last word until the space before that word when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>. Outlook (and perhaps other Microsoft applications) are the exceptions to that, as it includes that space before the deleted word. Is there any way to adjust Outlook's behavior to be more according to the aforementioned convention?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Outlook desktop client? If so, please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.
I tested in my environment Outlook 365 and found that Outlook also deletes the last word until the space before that word as other applications do.

Corrupted Outlook template file may cause issues like this. Please try to rename the NormalEmail.dotm file and restart your Outlook client to see if there is any difference. File location: drive:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried again and now it works properly. I'm very confused. I'm unable to reproduce the issue anymore. Problem solved, I guess.